# android.net.http.RequestQueue not found in andorid.jar

Tags: android

I am developing Android Twitter application. I downloaded TwitterClient Demo deom net.
But there is a class file "android.net.http.RequestQueue" that is not available in sDK component in android.jar. Please advise on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from *where* you have downloaded that Twitter demo example:

- originally, there was an [old 2007 demo](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/twitter-client-for-android-how-to-make-xml-over-http-calls/)
- a [new zip from October 2008](http://theregoesdave.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/twitterclient.zip) in [this post](http://theregoesdave.com/2008/10/13/4-twitter-applications-for-android-phones-with-screenshots/)

[image: Twitter client example]

- a [snippet from 2009](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/24/) with the following comment:

> `android.net.http.RequestQueue` is not an official part of the Android API, so it might go away or change in a future release.
>   You can tell by the `{@hide}` in the class-level JavaDoc comment in [`RequestQueue.java`](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/RequestQueue.java).

So if the recent APIs don't have this class at all anymore, you can fall back on `HttpURLConnection`, as in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/91450139824b8560/aeeac5ce05893c93?fwc=1).

> It seems safer to use the good ol' `HttpURLConnection` for HTTP calls then.
>   I suppose the `RequestQueue` was offered to save us the effort of spawning a separate thread before making the HTTP calls.

See the two approaches illustrated in [this tutorial here](http://www.anddev.org/doing_http_post_with_android-t492.html).